# How to set a fill style (texture) to an existing data URI in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, data-uri

I have an existing PNG data URI like:

```
let dataURI = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMAQMAAABsu86kAAAABlBMVEUAAAD+qAB849H0AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAxJREFUCNdjSEsgiACnWAlJEDYe/gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
```

I want to use that as a texture in my canvas that I am doing some draw operations on. I've tried a few things with `canvas.fillStyle`, but I'm not seeing that working. Colors work fine.

What would be the way to use a dataURI as a texture in drawing operations?

Comment: What do you mean: I want to use that as a texture?

Comment: I mean a fill style, so it repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load it as an image first (be sure to handle the asynchronous aspect), so basically to set an image as pattern:

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = imageIsReady;
img.src = "data: ....."; // full uri here

function imageIsReady() {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  // fill, etc.
}
```

Comment: So is it synchronous with that draw function in there? Do I need to wait for some event before I set the pattern?

Comment: @BBaysinger you just have to wait for the image to load (asynchronously) using onload as shown in the example (just replace drawImage with setting the pattern in the last example). After that you can reference it and draw in a synchronous (linear) fashion.

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting this error: core.es5.js:1020 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'addColorStop' on 'CanvasGradient': The value provided ('[object CanvasPattern]') could not be parsed as a color.

Comment: @BBaysinger seems as you're doing something funky there (and not really related to the original question). You cannot use patterns as color-stops in gradient though (only actual colors).

Comment: Ah, I see it. Somewhere down in someone else's code. Thanks for all the help.